# Pronunciation of "je me", "je te"

Tags: pronoms, prononciation

As I am looking at reflexive verbs and pronouns in French, a lot of sentences are constructed *je me (réveille)* or *je te (regarde)*. 
I know that for example, *je ne (sais pas)* the "je ne" is pronounced together.

Since "je me" and "je te" follow the same pattern of consonant-e-consonant-e,
would it be the same way, or would the two letter words be pronounced separately?

Comment: "Pronounced together" does not make sense. Are you talking about rhythmic group and intonation? Do you mean some letters are not sounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "pronounced together", I guess you mean pronounced in a single syllable.

This is indeed the usual case in casual spoken French where **/ʒəm/** and **/ʒmə/** can both be heard: *J'me réveille* and *Je m'réveille*, *J'te regarde* and *Je t'regarde*.

In formal, careful or regional variations speak, two syllables are used /ʒəmə/:
*Je me reveille, je te regarde*.

Comment: For a school setting, is there a preference between single vs two syllables?

Comment: It is better for a student to separate both syllables /ʒəmə/. Otherwise, the student might better use /ʒəm/ instead of /ʒmə/, the latter being slightly more informal.

Answer (score 1):

Both « je ne » and « je me » may be pronounced together : « j’ne », « j’me »

Same goes for « je te », « je nous », « je vous » …